# Jenkins integration with Jest

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jestjs

Is there a way to have Jenkins integration in the Javascript Jest testing framework that is built on top of Jasmine?

I've tried to integrate Jest with [jasmine-reporters](https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters), but didn't manage to get a JUnit XML output. I installed the reporters for Jasmine 1.3 with `npm install jasmine-reporters@~1.0.0` and then in my `setupTestFrameworkScriptFile`:

```
require('jasmine-reporters');

jasmine.VERBOSE = true;

jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter({
  savePath: "output/"
}));
```

When I run `jest` I get `NodeJS attempt: Arguments to path.join must be strings` or `NodeJS attempt: Object [object Object] has no method 'join'`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've managed to get a working version of it in this [repo](https://github.com/palcu/jest-example). The problem was I was not mocking `path` and `fs` in the test file.

Answer (score 4):

You're using the syntax of jasmine-reporters 2.x with the 1.x branch. Specifically, you are passing an object of options but you need to send positional arguments.

Don't do this:

```
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter({
  savePath: "output/"
}));
```

Instead, you should do this:

```
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter("output/"));
```

You can check out [the source](https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters/blob/jasmine1.x/src/jasmine.junit_reporter.js) for the list of available options. Here are the current options:

```
/**
 * Generates JUnit XML for the given spec run.
 * Allows the test results to be used in java based CI
 * systems like CruiseControl and Hudson.
 *
 * @param {string} [savePath] where to save the files
 * @param {boolean} [consolidate] whether to save nested describes within the
 *                  same file as their parent; default: true
 * @param {boolean} [useDotNotation] whether to separate suite names with
 *                  dots rather than spaces (ie "Class.init" not
 *                  "Class init"); default: true
 * @param {string} [filePrefix] is the string value that is prepended to the
 *                 xml output file; default: 'TEST-'
 * @param {boolean} [consolidateAll] whether to save test results from different
 *                  specs all in a single file; filePrefix is then the whole file
 *                  name without extension; default: false
 */
var JUnitXmlReporter = function(savePath, consolidate, useDotNotation, filePrefix, consolidateAll) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip but it's still not working and it gives the same error. https://github.com/palcu/jest-example

Comment: Thanks for the sample app, I can reproduce your error, though the reason why doesn't make sense to me. It looks like what is happening is the variables loaded via NodeJS `require` are getting mixed up somehow. I'm not sure why, and so far I've only seen this happen in the `jest` environment. I commented on the issue you opened in the jest repository with the observed behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [jest-junit](https://github.com/palmerj3/jest-junit) is also a option.