# Jenkins integration with JestJS

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jenkins, frameworks, jestjs

I had to fix my previous question. How can we integrate Jenkins with Jest for unit testing

And  what is the best JavaScript Testing framework for beginners

Comment: `Javascript Jenkins Integration` That means what?

Comment: How does JEST plugs in with Jenkins if you are trying to run some unit testing

Comment: Does this help? [Jenkins integration with Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25155767/jenkins-integration-with-jest)